# Does every asynchronous call in spring boot creates separate copy of every variable?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, asynchronous

I want to clarify three confusions here.

**Question 1)** My first question is that if we have a Java class in spring boot and we have one logger object at class level. Now inside this class in some function we have async call. Now when this asynchronous call will start . will it creates separate copy of all needed variables, in its stack ? or it will use same objects created at class level in main thread ?

For example imagine that we have some logger object at class level, which we are using for logging in main thread. Now if we access it in our async thread call in some method in same class. Will this async call use same logger object of main object or it will have its own new copy of logger object in its stack ?

**Question 2)** second questions is followed by answer of first questions, if async call will have separate copy of objects initialized in parent thread, then why exception occurs when both threads try to access same object at same time, as both have separate copies of same object.

**Question 3)** and if scope of any bean is singleton, still new copy of its object will be created in async call ? or same object will be shared among both main thread and async call ?

Answer (score 0):

The async call invokes a method, all local variables defined in that method exist on the stack frame of the method call. So those are copies that belong to that method invocation and they are accessed only by the thread executing the async method.

Instance variables and class variables, like the logger, are the same as for synchronous calls, they are not copied. If your async method references a repository, and another method references that same repository, both are calling the same object.

The other questions seem based on a misunderstanding of this first issue.

A spring component that you're calling the method on should not have conversational state, the instance members should be other spring components. Loggers are designed to be shared between threads.

Comment: but @Nathan here I have question, we read that every thread have its own copy of variables in its stack, then in case of async call why it would we using logger object of main thread ? why it would not have its own copy object of logger ?

Comment: @Johonsmuthio: the logger is referenced from a static variable, it doesn't belong to any one thread. Loggers are designed that way to minimize the amount of copying needed.

Comment: oh okay, thankyou so much for clarifying it. One last confusion. Suppose that if it was not logger. it was some other object like object of Student class and it was instantiated in parent thread. Now if it was accessed in async call, then there would be separate copy of student object on async threads stack and async call would be interacting with this copy not with student object instantiated in main thread. right @Nathan ?

Comment: @Johonsmuthio: no.  That wouldn't be copied. And if you pass entities between threads you risk having lazy loading fail when the hibernate session it is attached to isn't on the current thread.

Comment: I was going through this article (https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-concurrency/volatile.html#:~:text=The%20Java%20volatile%20keyword%20is%20intended%20to%20address%20variable%20visibility,read%20directly%20from%20main%20memory) and the author stated that " In a multithreaded application each thread copy variables from main memory into a CPU cache while working on them". But you are telling me that main thread and async call will not have different copy of same object. They will share same object . So do you think it is written wrong in this article ? @Nathan:

Comment: @Johonsmuthio: it's not wrong.  It's just not that useful  here.   Processor caches result in versions of an object diverging, then something (a happens-before edge) causes the changes to be flushed and reconciled. But thats not like making a defensive copy and having something separate. You really don't want 2 threads acting on the same entity object concurrently, there will be no telling which changes take effect once the  reconciliation happens.

Comment: Thankyou so much for explaining @Nathin, because I am facing same issue, In my spring boot service my async call and main thread are trying to access the httpbusineescontext object at same time and its causing exception. So I will look into that so that how can fix it. Thanks for your explanation and time.